# Does braille go to sheimos?

Tags: halacha, shemos-sacred-names, see-sight-vision-blind

Do things that, when written in print, require placement in *sheimos* (such as *shem Hashem* and *divrei Torah*), need to be placed in *sheimos* when written in Braille? Would we say that since most people can't read it, it doesn't need to be put into *sheimos*; or, would we say that since a large portion of the population can read it, that it would require placement in *sheimos*?

Comment: @Double I disagree -- I don't think that braille is a translation.

Comment: What else is it? A transliteration?

Comment: @DoubleAA Actual text!! See my answer to this question, as well as the answers to [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45200/5323). [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille) calls it a "tactile writing system" ....כתב עברי and כתב אשורי are not translations / transliterations of each other, are they?

Comment: @DoubleAA See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9518/5323

Comment: I assume braille would be considered the same as any other written language like English, German, or Hindi.

Comment: @Bachrach44 Are you responding to the question, or to my discussion with DoubleAA?

Comment: @Shokhet The initial question.

Comment: @Bachrach44 Then you were mechavein to Rav Zilberstein in the answer, I believe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Rav Zilberstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchok_Zilberstein) writes in [Veha'arev Na](http://www.feldheim.com/veha-arev-na.html) (page 441), that *sheimos* written in Braille require placement in *sheimos*, as they are read by a wide audience of blind people.

> **Challenge:** May *divrei Torah* written in braille be thrown in the garbage, or do they require *genizah* like *divrei Torah* written in
>   normal script?
>
> **Solution:** Since braille is a written language read by a wide audience of blind people, it has the same status as any other written
>   script. Therefore, *divrei Torah* written in braille must be placed in
>   *genizah*.

Comment: I have a question. If the normal and regular use of something transforms it into whatever It was originally meant to represent, but not be, then why doesn't the word Hashem turn into a Sheim Kadosh? Along these same lines when someone says 'nu' when they may not talk, at what point does 'nu' become an understood word and part of the language?

Comment: קונם is now a form of נדר. How'd that happen?

Comment: But....all the same -- we can't make something like that up unless a big rabbi tells us that it's true. The Gemara (or was it Mishna?) told us about the word קונם; Rav Zilberstein told us about braille. Ask the rabbis about "nu," come back and post an answer on MY, and ping me about it here. ( *I have a hunch that "Hashem" is different, because names of God, AFAICT, have **intrinsic** meaning* )

Comment: Didnt the gemara have drashos to include kinuyei nidarim? I don't think we can compare. This is a question not a disagreement.

Comment: @user6591 Not sure about the drashos thing. I wasn't taking this as a disagreement ("*I have a question*").

Answer (score 2):

Torah works written in braille do not require burial. Rav Shlomo Aviner was posed this question and [responded](http://www.ravaviner.com/2017/11/short-sweet-text-message-q-340.html)

> Q: Do Sifrei Kodesh written in Braille require being placed in a Geniza?
>
> A: No.  This is not the type of script the Torah was discussing.  There are Poskim, however, who do require them to be placed in a Geniza, since this is a type of lettering which many people consider to be a script (Ginzei Kodesh 10:3 #19 in the name of Ha-Rav Yosef Shalom Elyashiv).  But the basis[sic] Halachah is that one can be lenient.

Comment: Great. We now have a machlokes in the poskim. I’m surprised it took this long to find an arguing opinion.