# May one recite the Haftarah from a transliterated copy?

Tags: halacha, haftarah, transliteration

I know that public Torah reading needs to be read from a parchment. I saw some source stating that, ideally haftarah should also be read from parchment. However, I see numerous congregations allow reading it from a Chumash or designated haftarah book. These are in Hebrew.

Several months ago, a Bar Mitzvah boy in my shul recited the haftarah. He had trouble reading Hebrew, so someone gave him a transliterated version of his haftarah, and he read from it. Is this technique permissible? If not, why not?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/55494/759

Comment: Note the Shulchan Arukh forbids giving an Aliyah to someone who can't read Hebrew for "if he's not reading, [what is he saying a blessing on]?" Probably better for this kid to study something and give a Dvar Torah than to butcher a reading that most Rishonim disqualify him for anyway.

Comment: "some source," huh?

Comment: @DoubleAA he is sort of reading, just not Hebrew.